# ConfigurationProperties doesn't work when different prefixes and same values are used

Tags: java, spring

I have the following yaml-property file:

```
myPrefix: 
  value: Hello
myPrefix2:
  value: World
```

And two classes

```
@PropertySource("classpath:permission-config.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myPrefix")
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class ViewUsers {
    private String value;
}
```

and

```
@PropertySource("classpath:permission-config.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myPrefix2")
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class ManageUsers {
    private String value;
}
```

Then *null* is injected.
Or, if I try to use @Value then ONLY latest value is retrieved, which is the last one (World), the preceding ones are always ignored.

Comment: `@PropertySource` won't do a thing, you need to let Spring Boot load the yaml files by including those at startup (or move the properties to the general configuration file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following approach:

1. Remove `@Component` from configuration properties (`ViewUsers` and `ManageUsers`)
2. Instead, use the following construction:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:permission-config.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myPrefix")
public class ViewUsers {
    private String value; // getter, setter
}

@PropertySource("classpath:permission-config.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myPrefix2")
public class ManageUsers {
    private String value; // getter, setter
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ViewUsers.class, ManageUsers.class}
public class MySampleConfiguration {

    ... beans here...
}
```

Also make sure that Lombok annotations are working as expected (Try to use without lombok  just for the POC).

**Update 1**

As @M. Deinum has kindly stated, PropertySource like this doesn't work with yaml files.

You can try the following workaround:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name = "someName", value = "classpath:foo.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class MyConfig {
}


import org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader;
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        final List<PropertySource<?>> load = new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(name, resource.getResource());
        return load.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `@Component` as well. The `@PropertySource` is useless as that is for property files not yaml files.

Comment: both solutions don't work, still null fields are there

Comment: M. Deinum is right. I've totally missed this point. @user3475366: You should not use Property Source with Yaml Files, there are workarounds. Please try the updated answer